# How to contact someone asking them to be a co-supervisor

Tags: phd, thesis

I just finished my master's recently and I wish to do a PhD. I chose to continue working with my supervisor during the master's thesis, but I want to work on it with another professor as a co-supervisor who I met during my Erasmus stay in another university.

How can I contact the co-supervisor? Must I send a CV, a letter of motivation and a copy of my master's thesis attached or just an email asking for the co-supervising?

Comment: Please explain a bit more clearly what you mean with "I met". Are they aware of who you are? Do they know you enough to have a good impression of you?

Comment: Why do you want _a_ co-supervisor in general, and why would this _specific_ co-supervisor be an asset to you and your primary supervisor?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper We met in a seminar where we talked a bit about my work and studies in general. That's why I thought to send my CV so that he knows me better.

Comment: @JonCuster I want this co-supervisor because it's useful and enriching for my subject and my work.

Answer (score 10):

It would be a mistake to do this without the happy approval of your "current" supervisor. You need to discuss this with them if you haven't already.

And, the best way to bring the other person in to the process is to have the supervisor contact the other person. They can work out between them what they need to see about your history.

Of course, your supervisor might suggest that you make the contact. They will probably suggest how to do it properly.

However, a masters thesis and a cv in a first email isn't going to be helpful. It is too much information. First ask about the possibility and offer to send anything they need to help make a decision. You may also need to introduce the two people together, if they don't already know one another.

Comment: Thank you! It's helpful for me.